# Hlsl Texture2d array that can be accessed using a variable index

Tags: hlsl, directx11

I have tried

```
Texture2D textures[64] : register(t0);
SameplerState smpl;
float4 main(float2 uv : TEXCOODS1, uint i : Index) : SV_Target 
{
   return textures[i].Sample(smpl, uv);
}
```

But whe I compile I get an error that says array index must be literal experesion